# apply pairwise function on a pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, distance, pairwise

I have a dataframe, and I would like to apply my own distance pairwise.
The problem it that myDistance takes 2 dataframes, and using skelarn pairwise_distance or scipy pdist converts is to ndarray.
Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,3],[2,3,3,4],[4,1,3,2]],columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

This returns:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   3   3
1   2   3   3   4
2   4   1   3   2
```

Then:

```
def myDistance(f1,f2):
    return f1['A']-f2['A']

myDistance(df.loc[0],df.loc[1])
```

This works and returns -1.

But this doesn't, because pdist treat the df row as ndarray

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
dist = pdist(df,myDistance)
```

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Answer (score 0):

I'm think I understand you problem. You want to basically calculate the pairwise distances on only the `A` column of your dataframe. In that case, assuming column `A` is the first column on both dataframes, then you want to change your custom function to:

```
def myDistance(u, v):
    return((u - v)[0])  # get the 0th index, which corresponds to column A
```

Now run:

```
dist = pdist(df, myDistance)
```

Result:

```
array([-1., -3., -2.])
```